# How to combine ngrx effects calls in to a single stream?

Tags: javascript, angular

What I want to achieve is that I want to make a new request every 1s with the effect (backend will send back an array of 10 items) I want to combine that items in to a single entity collection & then loop through it in the template asynchronously.

Following is my effects. 
This is used to fetch data from the backend.

```
//effects.ts

  loadCourierItems$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItems),
      mergeMap(action =>
        this.defaultService.getCourierItems(
        ).pipe(
          map(CourierItems => CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess({ CourierItems })),
          catchError(error =>
            of(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsFailure({ error }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Following is my selector

```
//selector.ts

  export const selectCourierItemState = createFeatureSelector<CourierItemState>(
  CourierItemsFeatureKey
);

export const selectCourierItems = createSelector(selectCourierItemState, selectAll);
```

This is the component where I dispatch action to get data for the first time:

```
//app.component.ts

  constructor(private store: Store<CourierItemsState>) {
    this.store.dispatch(loadCourierItems())
  }

ngOnInit() {
this.courierItems$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectCourierItems))
}
```

```
//template.html


<div *ngFor="let item of courierItems$ | async as courier>
<p>{{courier.name}}</p>
<p>{{courier.loc_cur}}</p>

etc...
</div>

...
```

How can I do this?

What I want to achieve is that I want to make a new request every 1s with the effect (backend will send back an array of 10 items) I want to combine that items in to a single entity collection & then loop through it in the template asynchronously.

**Imp**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer. Just use addMany in the reducer.

```
on(CourierItemActions.loadCourierItemsSuccess,
    (state, action) => adapter.addMany(action.courierItems, state)
  ),
```